# Removing references in one-to-many and many-to-many relationships in MongoDB using Mongoose and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to mention that I am totally aware of the fact that MongoDB is not a relational database in the first place. However it supports referencing other documents, hence some functionality *should* be supported, imo. Anyways, I have this relationship: a Company `has many` Departments and one Department `belongs to` one Company.

### company.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CompanySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    departments: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Department'
    }],
    dateCreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    dateUpdated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Company', CompanySchema);
```

### department.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var DepartmentSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    company: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Company'
    },
    dateCreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    dateUpdated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Department', DepartmentSchema);
```

Now, I am writing Node.js logic to manipulate this data using API. I get that if I create a new Department, I should add a reference to Company and I should create its reference in this Company's departments array. Simple. But what if a user changes the Company property of a Department? Say, the HR Department used to belong to Company A, but a user now moves it to Company B? We need to remove the reference to this department from Company A's array and push it to Company B. The same is when we want to delete a department. We need to find a company it belongs to and dis-associate it. My solution is working ATM, but seems rather clumsy.

### routes.js

```
var Department = require('../../models/department'),
    Company = require('../../models/company');

module.exports = function(express) {
    var router = express.Router();

    router.route('/')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            // ...
        })
        .post(function(req, res) {
            // ...
        });

    router.route('/:id')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            // ...
        })
        .put(function(req, res) {

            // First we need to find the department with the request parameter id
            Department.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err, data) {
                if (err) return res.send(err);
                var department = data;
                // department.name = req.body.name || department.name; Not relevant

                // If the company to which the department belongs is changed
                if (department.company != req.body.company._id) {

                    // We should find the previous company
                    Company.findOne({ _id: department.company }, function(err, data) {
                        if (err) return res.send(err);
                        var company = data;

                        // Loop through its departments
                        for (var i = 0; i < company.departments.length; i++) {
                            if (company.departments[i].equals(department._id)) {

                                // And splice this array to remove the outdated reference
                                company.departments.splice(i, 1);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        company.save(function(err) {
                            if (err) return res.send(err);
                        });
                    });

                    // Now we find this new company which now holds the department in question
                    // and add our department as a reference
                    Company.findOne({ _id: req.body.company._id }, function(err, data) {
                        if (err) return res.send(err);
                        var company = data;
                        company.departments.push(department._id);
                        company.save(function(err) {
                            if (err) return res.send(err);
                        });
                    });
                }

                // department.company = req.body.company._id || department.company; Not relevant
                // department.dateUpdated = undefined; Not relevant

                // And finally save the department
                department.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) return res.send(err);
                    return res.json({ success: true, message: 'Department updated successfully.' });
                });
            });
        })
        .delete(function(req, res) {

            // Since we only have id of the department being deleted, we need to find it first
            Department.findOne({ _id: req.params.id}, function(err, data) {
                if (err) return res.send(err);
                var department = data;

                // Now we know the company it belongs to and should dis-associate them
                // by removing the company's reference to this department
                Company.findOne({ _id: department.company }, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) return res.send(err);
                    var company = data;

                    // Again we loop through the company's departments array to remove the ref
                    for (var i = 0; i < company.departments.length; i++) {
                        if (company.departments[i].equals(department._id)) {
                            company.departments.splice(i, 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    company.save(function(err) {
                        if (err) return res.send(err);
                    });

                    // I guess it should be synchronously AFTER everything is done,
                    // since if it is done in parallel with Department.findOne(..)
                    // piece, the remove part can happen BEFORE the dep is found
                    Department.remove({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err, data) {
                        if (err) return res.send(err);
                        return res.json({ success: true, message: 'Department deleted successfully.' });
                    });
                });
            });
        });

    return router;
};
```

Is there any elegant solution to this case or it is just as it should be?

Answer (score 0):

I see you have not yet captured the essence of the async nature of node.js ... for example you have a comment prior to department.save which says :   and finally ... well the earlier logic may very will be still executing at that time ...   also I strongly suggest you avoid your callback approach and learn how to do this using promises

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The async nature is not a big deal, this "finally" word I meant to use not in the context of the algorithm flow, but rather in the context of the logic. I'm aware that the `department.save()` may happen before or at the same time as the references update in the `company` model, it doesn't change anything and doesn't break the logic of the app. I will totally try to adopt the promises approach, though.